# Global variable undefined in function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign the global variables mouseX, mouseY to an event listener inside a function. When I try to use the variables inside another function, they come back undefined.

I know it's probably a problem with the scope of the variables being assigned to, but have not been able to figure it out, and any simple test code I write doesn't reproduce the problem.

What is causing this?

javascript:

```
var mouseX, mouseY;

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bars = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
  bars[i] = new Bar(ctx, 100+i*10, canvas.height, 5, 150);

for(var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
  bars[i].checkMouse(); 
  bars[i].display(); 
}

function Bar(ct, x, y, w, h){

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y; 
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.y -= this.h;

  this.display = function() {
    ct.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    ct.fill();
  }  
  this.checkMouse = function() { 
    //if(mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= this.x + this.w){
    //this.y = mouseY; this.h = height-mouseY; 
    console.log(mouseX);  //////mouseX is undefined?
    //} 
  }  
}  

function getMouse(event) {
  mouseX = event.offsetX;
  mouseY = event.offsetY;
  var coords = "mouseX: " + mouseX + ", mouseY: " + mouseY;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = coords;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    canvas{
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        position:relative;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display">&nbsp</div>
<canvas onmousemove="getMouse(event)" id="myCanvas" width="500"      height="200">
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pass mouseX in function like this this.checkMouse = function(mouseX) { //

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: You aren't setting `mouseX` and `mouseY` until you call `getMouse` yet you only call `bars[i].checkMouse();` *before* the event is even run.

Comment: As @h2ooooooo said, `mouseX` and `mouseY` has no value. There are declare without value. The primitive value of a variable in javascript is `undefined`. Declare it do nothing to avoid it. Just set a value for that or mkae a check before `console.log` and you are fine

Comment: @h2oooooo Thanks! I see I had the main check() and displa() loop just occurring once, as if it would behave as a main loop, which is what I want. I copied it into getMouse() to fix that. I guess it was an macro organization problem, not a scope issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as h2oooooo pointed out:
This loop was running just once:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
bars[i].checkMouse(); 
bars[i].display(); 
}
```

When it is supposed to behave like a main loop. Copying it into the getMouse() function fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's not a problem with the scopeing, but a problem with the order of execution of your code fragments.

A script file gets executed, when loaded completely. So all your definitions, the Creation of your objects and invokes the method which doesn't work in your example.

The function, in which `mouseX` and `mouseY` get initialized, gets executed in the `mouseover` Event of the canvas and though gets executed later.

So all in all: When your method is fired, the variables are uninitialized, because they get initialized in a function, which is executed later.

The best idea would be, to couple the execution of the method which is problematic to the execution of the `getMouse` function.

Please note that relying on such a global state, especially when creating such race conditions, is a very bad style, because it leads to issues like that and gets nearly unmaintainable when your project grows.